# Canon LiDE 600F FAU on Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, scanner

I have been able to use my Canon LiDE 600F scanner under Snow Leopard to scan paper sheet, after installing Canon's latest driver software.

However, I cannot find a way to make the FAU (Film Adaptor Unit) to work:

- Canon's software want to calibrate it first and gives an error message "Calibration cannot be performed. Pull out the film. 182.0.0". (of course there is no film).
- Hamrick's VueScan doesn't seem to support the FAU
- Apple's Image Capture doesn't propose a film option either

Did I miss something?
Did somebody manage to scan film (positive or negative) using the LiDE 600F under Snow Leopard?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did not try this with snow leopard yet but decent result with sane on leopard with an old canon scanner.
Never mind .... http://www.juergen-ernst.de/info_sane.html is the development page for this scanner and it is unsupported for now.